# Error: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm not sure why I am getting this error. I had it working before and now it's not.  This is the inner exception error message:

EntitySqlException: The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 78.

This is the line of code that it's singling out:

```
Attending attending = db.Attendings.Find(userId);
```

This is the code in the context of the controller:

```
public ActionResult Attendees(int? id)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Attending attending = db.Attendings.Find(userId);
        if (attending == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        PopulateBeverageDropDownList(attending.BeverageId);

        return View(attending);
    }
```

I have looked all over stackoverflow and Google, but even though I find similar problems, I still cannot figure out how to solve my own.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to use the PK from one of my models and the userId from asp.net identity concurrently.  This used to work fine, except I don't know what's changed for this error to pop up.  This is the link to my repository to view the code in its entirety: https://github.com/alec9876/Firepit/tree/master/Firepit

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-entities-using-primary-keys) is used to get an entity via it's primary key. For the `Attendees` model the primary key is `AttendeeID`, which is, unlike the `userId`, an `int`.
If you want to get the `Attending` by it's id, you can just pass the `id` variable to `Find`. If you want to get `Attendings` of a user, you could get the `AttendeeID` of the user, and use [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) to get the `Attendings`, e.g.:

```
 db.Attendings.Where(x => x.AttendeeId == attendeeId)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I tried what you suggested, but now I'm getting this error now:

The view 'Attendees' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Attendance/Attendees.aspx
~/Views/Attendance/Attendees.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Attendees.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Attendees.ascx
~/Views/Attendance/Attendees.cshtml
~/Views/Attendance/Attendees.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Attendees.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Attendees.vbhtml

Any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome, the error just indicates that you did not create a `Attendees` view, which is expected from the line `return View(attending);`. See the [ASP.NET Core MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) for further information.